# Overheating RAM, ddr2 motherboard 2 slots

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

Recently, I bought a new memory stick to speed up my machine, which is the exact product that I have been using. The problem is either of the RAM overheats like after 5 minutes once my computer turns on. I have noticed this when I checked my memory sticks, then found out that one of them is abnormally heating up. I have also tried to switch their slots but still, one of them will cause my computer to hang. So, now I'm running it with only 1 stick, but I'm not having any trouble. Hoping that this will be solved.

Comment: Is it always the same stick that heats up? Have you tried using each of the sticks alone?

Comment: It asked the shop to replace the new stick. But now, my old stick has been heating up when I use them together.
And yes, I have tried to use the sticks alone

Comment: As an aside, I think you need to take regular back ups in-case it is hardware fault which does permanent damage!

Comment: It is also because of the BIOS unequal distribution of voltage?

Comment: Can you clear up which stick is heating up?  Your question states that "either of the RAM overheats".  Does that mean that it is not predictable as to which stick is overheating?  Is it the one that is always in slot 0 or slot 1?  What is telling you the stick is overheating?  By chance, is there hot air from the CPU fan being reflected from the heat sink onto that first stick of RAM?  Are you using RAM with heat sinks mounted on them?  Any pictures of your setup?  Motherboard model?  Specific info on the Ram?

Comment: It can either be a motherboard design fault or it can be that the RAM stick have different Data Rates and/or Bus Clock. Can you tell us what type of DDR2 are written on the sticks. eg. DDR2-800, DDR2-1066. It also could be from the BIOS settings. Have you checked the overclock setting in your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 possible reasons for the issue:
- faulty new memory module
- faulty power circuit of one of the memory slots.

It's simple to check: if the heated memory module is always the same whatever slot you put it to - it is an issue with RAM.
If any of the RAM modules are heated in the same slot - it is an issue with the power source supplied to the memory slot.

It can't be a frequency issue because as you posted - you have two identical modules - and you can't set different frequencies for different slots. So, they are working at the same speed.

It is also wrong that BIOS is responsible for power supplying to the RAM subsystem. BIOS is capable only to gather information from sensors of what voltage is supplied from PSU. Voltage that is powering RAM slots is 1.8V and is generated by DC-DC convertor. +5V is supplied to the motherboard, is converted to 2.5V and after that to 1.8 V.
This is how the voltages are obtained: http://laptoprepairegypt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/02074fb6595ca5f3102a89db6a95b59a.jpg

You can check what voltage is on your RAM slots 
You need to put the red pin of the multimeter of the corresponding +V contact, and a black one - on the ground.
Here is the picture which contacts you need to check and and what are the voltages there: http://www.rom.by/files/DDR2_pin.gif

Here is the video of the whole process:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCmVGKbgS1k